# exec_bad_access while accessing NSArray returned from FetchRequest

Tags: iphone

I have been trying hard to figure whats going wrong the the code below.
I find this code working when app is running for the first time in the simulator.
but when I close the simulator, open it next time and try deleting a record, that time i get exec_bad_access error.

```
    NSFetchRequest *requestToDelete = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[requestToDelete setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicateWithTitle = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"RecipeId == %@", strRecipeId];
[requestToDelete setPredicate:predicateWithTitle];

NSError *errorInRequest = nil;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestToDelete error:&errorInRequest];
[requestToDelete release];

if(errorInRequest!=nil )
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", errorInRequest, [errorInRequest userInfo]);
    abort();
}

if(results!=nil && [results count] > 0)
{
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:[results objectAtIndex:0]];
            // Failing at this line
            // To be specific, this is causing error : [results objectAtIndex:0]
            // more strange part is, [results count] is 1
}
```

I tried to find out whether i am trying to access any released object. but could not figure it out. I ran the applicaion with "Zombies" instrument. It indicates that accessing an released NSNumber object is causing the issue.
I built the application using "Build and Analyze" option. Everything seems to be ok.
Can Anybody help me out?

. . . One more thing, The error **does not occur always**. if there are more than 1 records, the error may or may not occur. But If there is just a single record remaining to be deleted, the error occurs always.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any relationships off Recipe that may be causing this?

(Also, you can simply do `if (errorRequest)` and `if ([results count]) {...`)

Comment: Also, there is a single table in Database. So no relationships

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you don't release requestToDelete until you're done? :-)